Identify this movie about a family with a psychopath son
I saw a movie a couple of years back and I'm trying to find it.
What I can remember is, a family – a wife, father, older daughter and younger son – just moved into a new house. I think it was because the father got into some trouble. The "bad guys" come and they start looking for something, but the son is some sort of psychopath and I'm pretty sure he kills them. That's about all I can remember.


Could be The Aggression Scale (2012).
The following are snippets from reviews. First, we meet the ''bad guys'':

Someone has stolen money from a mob boss, and he wants it back. He
  hands off a list of suspects to his number one henchman with a simple
  order: kill every person on this list until you get to the embezzler,
  get the money back and kill him too.

Meanwhile, we're introduced to the family:

Newlyweds Bill and Maggie move to the country to start a new life.
  They are joined by Bill’s son Owen and Maggie’s daughter, Lauren. It
  seems, however, that the family left some loose ends behind in the
  city.

This segment talks a bit about Owen (pretty much how you described him!):

The syndicate boss, Mr. Bellavance, sends a group of his men to the
  family’s home to teach them a lesson. However, he was not counting
  on Owen. Recently sprung from a juvie mental hospital, Owen has some
  issues, including a penchant for spectacular violence.

You can watch a trailer here.
~ Synopsis edited from ShockTillYouDrop and BadassDigest
